# Names of nodes at depth d for every descendant leaf

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a category hierarchy that products are attached to. That category hierarchy is saved as an adjacency list. Products can be attached to any category nodes at any level. The category hierarchy is a tree.

I would like to...

1. get the name of every level 3 category...
2. per product...
3. where that product is attached to any level 3 category node...
4. or a descendant of a level 3 node.

I know I can [materialize the hierarchy](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown), and from that I've been able to satisfy all requirements but the last. I always lose some products or categories.

Given

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (p_id varchar PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE category (c_id varchar PRIMARY KEY, parent_c_id varchar);
CREATE TABLE product_category (
    p_id varchar,
    c_id varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (p_id, c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES product (p_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES category (c_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
                                                                       
INSERT INTO product (p_id) VALUES
('p_01'),
('p_02'),
('p_03'),
('p_04'),
('p_05');
                                                                       
INSERT INTO category (c_id, parent_c_id) VALUES
('c_0_1', NULL),
-- L1
('c_1_1', 'c_0_1'),
('c_1_2', 'c_0_1'),
('c_1_3', 'c_0_1'),
-- L2
('c_2_1', 'c_1_1'),
('c_2_2', 'c_1_1'),
('c_2_3', 'c_1_2'),
('c_2_4', 'c_1_3'),
-- L3
('c_3_1', 'c_2_1'),
('c_3_2', 'c_2_2'),
('c_3_3', 'c_2_3'),
('c_3_4', 'c_2_4'),
-- L4
('c_4_1', 'c_3_1'),
('c_4_2', 'c_3_2'),
('c_4_3', 'c_3_3'),
('c_4_4', 'c_3_4');
                                                                       
INSERT INTO product_category (p_id, c_id) VALUES
-- p_01 explicitly attached to every level in path 1; include.
('p_01', 'c_0_1'),
('p_01', 'c_2_1'),
('p_01', 'c_3_1'),
('p_01', 'c_4_1'),
-- p_02 explicitly attached to desired level in paths 1 and 3; include both.
('p_02', 'c_3_3'),
('p_02', 'c_3_4'),
-- p_03 explicitly attached to super-level in path 3; exclude.
('p_03', 'c_2_4'),
-- p_04 explicitly attached to sub-level in path 1,
-- transitively to desired level in path 1; include.
('p_04', 'c_4_2');
-- p_05 not attached at all.
```

I would like to end up with something like

```
 p_id |      c_id
------+----------------
 p_01 | {c_3_1}
 p_02 | {c_3_3, c_3_4}
 p_04 | {c_3_2}
(3 rows)
```

but the closest I have gotten is

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE category_tree (c_id, parent_c_id, depth, path) AS (
    SELECT c_id, parent_c_id, 0 AS depth, ARRAY[]::varchar[]
    FROM category
    WHERE parent_c_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.c_id, c.parent_c_id, ct.depth + 1, path || c.c_id
    FROM category_tree AS ct
    INNER JOIN category AS c ON c.parent_c_id = ct.c_id
)
SELECT *
INTO TEMP TABLE t_category_path
FROM category_tree;

SELECT p.p_id, ARRAY_AGG(c_id) category_names
FROM product AS p,
   (SELECT DISTINCT t1.c_id, p_id
    FROM product_category AS pc
    INNER JOIN t_category_path AS t1 ON pc.c_id = t1.c_id
    WHERE t1.depth = 3
    ORDER BY c_id) x
WHERE p.p_id = x.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id;
```

```
 p_id | category_names
------+----------------
 p_01 | {c_3_1}
 p_02 | {c_3_4,c_3_3}
(2 rows)
```

- The order of categories is irrelevent (I want a set, not a list).
- I can tolerate duplicate categories far better than missing categories or products.
- I have some liberty to adjust the schema.

```
> select version();
                                                   version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.12 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9608628840a9895240c9d4c72fe162c4)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT c_id, parent_c_id, 0 as level, NULL AS level3_category
    FROM category
    WHERE parent_c_id IS NULL
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT
        c.c_id,
        cte.parent_c_id,
        cte.level + 1,
        CASE                                                  -- 1
            WHEN cte.level + 1 = 3 THEN c.c_id
            ELSE cte.level3_category
        END
    FROM
        category c
    JOIN 
        cte
    ON c.parent_c_id = cte.c_id
)
SELECT 
    p_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT level3_category) as c_id               -- 2
FROM 
    cte
JOIN 
    product_category pc
ON cte.c_id = pc.c_id AND cte.level3_category IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p_id
```

1. This `CASE` clause stores the current name if and only if it is level 3. If it is less, than it returns `NULL`, if it is greater, it takes the level 3 value.
2. `DISTINCT` is allowed in `GROUP BY` aggregates to eliminate non-distinct values.

Comment: Yes, this appears to behave exactly as desired. It's surprisingly fast, too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` and `not exists` with `join`s to get a particular depth:

```
select p.p_id, array_agg(pc.c_id)
from products p join
     product_category pc
     on p.p_id = pc.p_id
where exists (select 1
              from category_tree ct join
                   category_tree ctp
                   on ct.parent_cid = ctp.cid join
                   category_tree ctp2
                   on ctp.parent_cid = ctp2.cid                   
              where ct.cid = pc.c_id
             ) and
       
       not exists (select 1
                   from category_tree ct join
                        category_tree ctp
                        on ct.parent_cid = ctp.cid join
                        category_tree ctp2
                        on ctp.parent_cid = ctp2.cid join                 
                        category_tree ctp3
                        on ctp2.parent_cid = ctp3.cid                   
                   where ct.cid = pc.c_id
                  )
group by p.p_id;
```